# Weight Paint Normalize Moves Mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a problem with a mesh that moves unexpectedly with a bone, so I thought that I might want to normalize all the bone weights to get a "true" picture of the weights. Normalizing however, moves the mesh around which I didn't expect. (some of the bones are posed when I do normalize).

My impression was that the overall bone-influence result would be the same after normalizing, but since the mesh moves around, it seems this isn't so. Am I doing something wrong, or did I just mis-understand the normalize-all operation? (I tried both with and without any bones selected).

(also, noob-alert)

EDIT: Ok, I may have totally misunderstood something. But I tried making a simple skeleton and object: Two bones controlling a cube'ish thing. Painted all vertices red for both bones (weight 1.0 for both bones), and then picked normalize all. Now one bone had weight 1.0 on a vertex, the other bone got 0.0. I understand that blender has now made sure total weight <=1, but I would have expected the weight to have been shared, something like 0.5 for each bone on that vertex.

[image: Normalize causes one bone to be "forgotten"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "stilltrying" from blenderartists.org, I found my answer.

The little Normalize All option called "Lock Active" is on pr default, meaning the active vertex group was unchanged. This of course leads to the relative weights being changed, thus causing the mesh to move due to the Normalize All operation.